# vsftpd error cannot bind socket or connect

Tags: ftp, vsftpd

I just installed `vsftpd` on a rackspace cloudserver running ubuntu.

After a restart I get the following error:

`root@scrapy:~# vsftpd
500 OOPS: could not bind listening IPv4 socket`

And this error in `Transmit` when I try to ftp:

`Error -203: miscellaneous error occurred while trying to login to the host`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this is helpful:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=264003

In particular:

Edit the /etc/vsftpd.conf and make sure that you have commented out the "listen=YES", if you are trying to run vsftpd through xinetd.

I'd run a stop and make sure noone is listening before starting the daemon.

Edit: Re: your second issue, you need to allow FTP on your firewall.

You need port 20/21 tcp depending on active or passive FTP. slacksite.com/other/ftp.html

Comment: Now I get the error `Connection Refused`

Comment: Is that from your ftp client that gives the Connection Refused message?  In that case, check your firewall.  You need port 20/21 tcp depending on active or passive FTP.  http://slacksite.com/other/ftp.html

Comment: From my FTP client. Yes.

Comment: See above re firewall requirements for FTP.

Comment: Make that an answer so I can choose it as correct dmourati?